# Fill empty line in a column based on match between two other columns

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

File `а.txt`:

```
snp chr pos effect  noneffect   eaf beta    se  pval    pval    pval
chr:1   1   101 A   G   0.3 -0.04   0.03    0.1 0.44    0.936
chr:1   1   1000    B   L   0.01    0.03    0.8 0.427   0.6804
```

Some of the lines from `а.txt` might miss `$6` values (like second line here).
File `b.txt`

```
101 0.1
1000 0.2
```

I am looking for a way how to replace `$6` of `a.txt` with `$2` from `b.txt`

I tried the below command which didn't solve the problem:

```
awk '$6 {print $3,$6} !$6 {print $3,$2}' b.txt a.txt
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$3 in a{print}' b.txt a.txt
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: So, you want to use `b.txt` as a lookup table for `$6` of `a.txt`, with `$3` as key?

Comment: Yes, exactly its what im looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you can use the number of fields `NF` to determine if `$6` is missing, you could do

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} NF<11 {$6 = a[$3] OFS $6} {print}' b.txt a.txt
```

If you want to prettify the output, pipe it through `column -t`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} NF<11 {$6 = a[$3] OFS $6} {print}' b.txt a.txt | column -t
SNP               CHR  POS    EFFECT_ALLELE  NON_EFFECT_ALLELE  EAF       BETA        SE         PVALUE    INFO      HWE
chr:1:10177:AC:A  1    10177  A              AC                 0.376827  -0.0447626  0.0316126  0.156783  0.422784  0.936182
chr:1:10352:TA:T  1    10352  T              TA                 0.43176   0.00727013  0.0309617  0.814356  0.427932  0.680802
```